# devex pivot grid does not total calculated column

Tags: c#, sql, devexpress, pivot

[image]

kisibasi is a calculated value and it it result of satisMiktari/pax like 51/3 = 17
and total adding per values. 
for example emin total should be like: 105/45= 2,311 but it adding 17,00+1,29 as its normal behaivour.

how can I find the true calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with not using that total. because there is no solution for it.